# Using FormFlow dialog in Bot Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework

I am using Bot Framework SDK v-4.x based on .Net Core. I have couple of dialogs created which I am able to flow through using `DialogContext.Begin`, `DialogContext.End` and `DialogContext.Continue`. Everything works fine, but now I want to implement a FormFlow in the middle of a conversation. I referred this link- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

I posted this on Github (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/227) and based on the solution this is what I tried-

```
[Serializable]
public class HelpForm
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public DateTime BestTimeToContact { get; set; }
    public List<Priority> Priority { get; set; }
    public static IForm<HelpForm> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<HelpForm>()
            .Message("Please fill out the details as prompted.")
            .Build();
    }
}

public enum Priority
{
    Low,
    Medium,
    High
}
```

In my `OnTurn` event of my bot, I am doing something like this-

`await Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Classic.Dialogs.Conversation.SendAsync(context, () => FormDialog.FromForm(HelpForm.BuildForm)); //context is of type ITurnContext`

This doesn't seem to work and I get a response in the emulator as

> Sorry, my bot code is having an issue.

Also, this link- https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/wiki/Using-Classic-V3-Dialogs-with-V4-SDK says that `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Classic` is not supported in .Net Core.
Any help with this please?

**Update**

Based on Fei's comment, I got the exception details. `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'System.RuntimeType' in Assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' is not marked as serializable.`. Although my HelpForm class is marked with `Serializable`.

Looking at the metadata for `FormFlow` class it is not marked with `Serializable` attribute.

[image]

Note sure if that is what the error is about.

Comment: `Sorry, my bot code is having an issue.` You can try to trace/check the detailed exception message via ***CatchExceptionMiddleware***.

Comment: @FeiHan I get error something like this- `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'System.RuntimeType' in Assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' is not marked as serializable.`. Although my `HelpForm` class is marked with `Serializable`.

Comment: Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Classic has been removed.  FormFlow is not currently supported in v4.  I've been working on a port here: https://github.com/EricDahlvang/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow (not ready for release yet)

Comment: There is an github issue for FormBuilder in V4 https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/561

Comment: The Bot Builder Community released a [FormFlow version for Bot Builder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.FormFlow/) v4 last week.  [Read me](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.FormFlow/README.md)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bot Builder V3 **FormFlow** dialogs can now be used in the context of a V4 bot by using the recently released [Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.FormFlow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.FormFlow/) library.

Your **HelpForm** can be added to a V4 DialogSet in the same way as other V4 ComponentDialogs:

```
_dialogs.Add(FormDialog.FromForm(HelpForm.BuildForm));
```

Here is a more complete example:

Accessors:

```
public class TestEchoBotAccessors
{
    public TestEchoBotAccessors(ConversationState conversationState)
    {
        ConversationState = conversationState ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(conversationState));
    }

    public ConversationState ConversationState { get; }
    public IStatePropertyAccessor<DialogState> ConversationDialogState { get; set; }
}
```

Startup.cs ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddBot<TestEchoBotBot>(options =>
    {
        IStorage dataStore = new MemoryStorage();
        options.State.Add(new ConversationState(dataStore));
        options.Middleware.Add(new AutoSaveStateMiddleware(options.State.ToArray()));

        var secretKey = Configuration.GetSection("botFileSecret")?.Value;
        var botFilePath = Configuration.GetSection("botFilePath")?.Value;

        // Loads .bot configuration file and adds a singleton that your Bot can access through dependency injection.
        var botConfig = BotConfiguration.Load(botFilePath ?? @".\TestEchoBot.bot", secretKey);
        services.AddSingleton(sp => botConfig ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"The .bot config file could not be loaded. ({botConfig})"));

        // Retrieve current endpoint.
        var environment = _isProduction ? "production" : "development";
        var service = botConfig.Services.Where(s => s.Type == "endpoint" && s.Name == environment).FirstOrDefault();
        if (!(service is EndpointService endpointService))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"The .bot file does not contain an endpoint with name '{environment}'.");
        }

        options.CredentialProvider = new SimpleCredentialProvider(endpointService.AppId, endpointService.AppPassword);
    });

    services.AddSingleton(sp =>
    {
        var options = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<BotFrameworkOptions>>().Value;
        var conversationState = options.State.OfType<ConversationState>().FirstOrDefault();
        var accessors = new TestEchoBotAccessors(conversationState)
        {
            ConversationDialogState = conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState")
        };
        return accessors;
    });
}
```

Bot code:

```
public class TestEchoBotBot : IBot
{
    private readonly TestEchoBotAccessors _accessors;
    private DialogSet _dialogs;

    public TestEchoBotBot(TestEchoBotAccessors accessors, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (loggerFactory == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));
        }

        _dialogs = new DialogSet(accessors.ConversationDialogState);
        _dialogs.Add(FormDialog.FromForm(HelpForm.BuildForm));
        _accessors = accessors ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(accessors));
    }

    public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            var dialogContext = await _dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
            if (turnContext.Activity.Text?.ToUpper() == "HELP")
            {
                await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(typeof(HelpForm).Name, null, cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                var dialogResult = await dialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);
                if ((dialogResult.Status == DialogTurnStatus.Cancelled || dialogResult.Status == DialogTurnStatus.Empty))
                {
                    var responseMessage = $"You sent '{turnContext.Activity.Text}'\n";
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(responseMessage);
                }
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as you've discovered, FormFlow doesn't work with v4.

V4 comes with a very structured waterfall dialog however, and this can be used to implement a functionality similar to FormFlow. The sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt) shows how to use waterfall dialogs to ask a user a series of questions such as name, age and address. The Prompt dialog class in particular is suited for this type of task. There is a confirm prompt included that you can implement at the end of the dialog to mimic FormFlow's confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4993) thread.

The Bot Builder Community has released a FormFlow implementation for V4:  -

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.FormFlow/
  with source here:
- https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.FormFlow/README.md